# Multiple file upload in each inputs using CodeIgniter and Ajax with multiple input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am not able to upload multiple images in a folder in codeigniter. I have used this reference [Multiple image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633610/multiple-file-upload-in-each-inputs-using-codeigniter-and-ajax). Someone please help me. Atleast the author of this reference please help me to sort out this problem. Here is my code

**View**

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" class="file_input" multiple />
<input type="file" name="images[]" class="file_input" multiple />
<input type="file" name="images[]" class="file_input" multiple />
<input type="file" name="images[]" class="file_input" multiple />
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#save').on('click', function(){
    var fileInputs = $('.file_input');
    var formData = new FormData();
    $.each(fileInputs, function(i,fileInput){
        if( fileInput.files.length > 0 ){
            $.each(fileInput.files, function(k,file){
                formData.append('images[]', file);
            });
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>exerciseset/process', 
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    method: 'post',

        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function process()
{
$fileuploadurl = base_url() . "study_set/";
    $config['upload_path'] = 'study_set/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|mp3|mp4';
    $config['max_filename'] = '255';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['max_size'] = '25000000';
$F = array();

$count_uploaded_files = count( $_FILES['images']['name'] );

$files = $_FILES;
for( $i = 0; $i < $count_uploaded_files; $i++ )
{
    $_FILES['userfile'] = [$files['images']['name'][$i]];

    $F[] = $_FILES['userfile'];

    // Here is where you do your CodeIgniter upload ...
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->data($_FILES['userfile']); 
                if (!$this->upload->data('images')) {
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                } 
}

echo json_encode($F);
}
```

It returns the images name into array but not able to upload it into folder. And also i need  each image name in separate variable. Please help me i am in hurry.

Comment: Why you are using multiple file with same name having `multilple` attribute?

Comment: which server are you using wamp or lamp?

Comment: can you print this  $_FILES['userfile']

Comment: I am using Xampp

Comment: have you created `study_set` folder in root folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple files upload in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113832/multiple-files-upload-in-codeigniter)

Comment: May $_FILES['userfile'] not getting file object that's why it not upload like it not getting temp name

Comment: Yes i have created the folder. Its working for single file upload with single input field. I want to upload different files by using 4 input fields

Comment: Is there anyone to help me

Answer (score 0):

In your code it seems like you missed to upload file. Hence it will not moved to specific folder. Please check below, Hope it will help you.

```
public function process()
{
    $fileuploadurl = base_url() . "study_set/";
    $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . 'uploads/study_set/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|mp3|mp4';
    $config['max_filename'] = '255';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['max_size'] = '25000000';
    $F = array();

    $count_uploaded_files = count( $_FILES['images']);
    $result = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < $count_uploaded_files; $i++ )
    {
        $_FILES["file"]["name"] = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
        $_FILES["file"]["type"] = $_FILES["images"]["type"][$i];
        $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $_FILES["file"]["error"] = $_FILES["images"]["error"][$i];
        $_FILES["file"]["size"] = $_FILES["images"]["size"][$i];
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
            $result['errors'][] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }else{ 
            $result['success'][] = $this->upload->data(); 
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Please make sure you have specified correct folder path and folder has enough permissions to write files.

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: I have given the permissions to write in that folder. Your code is not working.

Comment: Use debugger tool and share your ajax response, So I can help you better.

Comment: (4) ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"]0: "1.jpg"1: "2.jpg"2: "3.jpg"3: "4.jpg"length: 4__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: I am getting the image from the fields to the controller only it is not updating in the folder

Comment: It seems like you are doing something wrong, If you gave used above code than you will get two array in response. Array of success and errors. Please check your code again or copy and paste my whole code and check. also add your upload path like `APPPATH . 'uploads/study_set/';`

Comment: I had added the response please check it

Comment: I have updated my answer. Where is your study_set is located in sile structure? Can you please specify your path..?