# how to upload multi file type with one form in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one multi-part form. I want to upload 5 images and one video with this form. I do not want using AJAX upload.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('file'        , 'lang:pic'            , 'callback_multiple_upload');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('video'       , 'lang:video'          , 'callback_video_upload');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what are the errors?

Comment: Don't use set rules for that, that's not what it's for and this methodology will give you more issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633610/multiple-file-upload-in-each-inputs-using-codeigniter-and-ajax

Comment: @AbdullaNilam user "doesn't want to use ajax"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the upload class for each file and set the required file type i.e.

```
$config['upload_path']= './uploads/files/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'docx|doc|pdf|txt|odt';
$config['max_size']             = 10000;
$config['max_width']            = 1024;
$config['max_height']           = 768;
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->upload->do_upload();
//check errors in first upload.
```

then for video

```
$config['upload_path']= './uploads/videos/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'mp4|flv';
$config['max_size']             = 10000;
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->upload->do_upload();
```

Comment: Important to note: upload class can only upload one image at a time, in order to upload more you need to use a foreach loop and the files array together with the upload class.

Comment: and i should set second parameter to "TRUE".

$this->upload->initialize($config,TRUE);

Comment: @MortezaMousavi if you autoload the upload class then TRUE is not required. see more at: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 2):

For multiple images

```
 $config['upload_path'] = PATH; //add path according to your requirements 
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
 $config['overwrite'] = false; //OR true
 $config['max_size'] = '100000'; //You can change it
 $this->load->library('upload');
 $files = $_FILES;
 $number_of_files = count($_FILES['pic']['name']); //"pic" is name of FILE input 
 //images name will be details0, details1, details2 and soo on.
 $errors = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
$_FILES['pic']['name'] = "details" . $i . ".jpg"; //If you want to change the name of images change "details" with your require name
$_FILES['pic']['type'] = $files['pic']['type'][$i];
$_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'] = $files['pic']['tmp_name'][$i];
$_FILES['pic']['error'] = $files['pic']['error'][$i];
$_FILES['pic']['size'] = $files['pic']['size'][$i];
$this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("pic")) 
    {
       $errors++;
    }
} 
    if ($errors > 0) 
    {
       echo $errors . "File(s) could not be uploaded";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple file uploading

```
$filesCount = count($_FILES['userFiles']['name']);
            for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
                $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['userFiles']['size'][$i];
                $upload_path ="/test/assets/upload";

                $output_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $upload_path;
                $config['upload_path'] = $output_dir;

               // $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|mp4; //add other_extensions';
                $config['file_name'] = 'PIC_'.$user_id.'_'.$i;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){

                    $fileData = $this->upload->data();

                    $img_insert_array = array('user_id'=>$user_id,'profile_pic'=> $fileData['file_name']);
                    $res = $this->Test_model->update_img($img_insert_array );

                   //here insert in db
                    echo "uploaded successful";
                }
                else {
                        print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
                        }

            }
```