# Issue while uploading multiple images using single input in codeiginiter with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to upload multiple images using single input in codeigniter with ajax, here's my code.
HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple />
```

AJAX:

```
$("#addItems").on("submit",function(even)
{
    even.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url         : base_url+"dashboard/insert_item",
        type        : "POST",
        data        : new FormData(this),
        cache       : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success     : function(data)
        {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data.code == 201)
            {
                $.toaster({ title : 'Message', priority : 'success', message : data.record });
            }
            else
            {
                $.toaster({ title : 'Error', priority : 'danger', message : data.errors });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My Controller Code:

```
if ( !empty($_FILES) ) {
    $this->load->library('upload');

    //Configure upload.
    $this->upload->initialize(array(
        "allowed_types" => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
        "upload_path"   => "./uploads/"
    ));

    //Perform upload.
    if($this->upload->do_upload("files")) 
    {
        $uploaded = $this->upload->data();
        echo '<pre>';
        var_export($uploaded);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    else
    {
        die('UPLOAD FAILED');
    } 
    // $response = makeResponse(201,'success','','Item Added Successfully!');
}
```

The issue is that i am getting only one image in new FormData, i have tried every thing but still getting one image not multiple images in my FormData Object.
How can i get all images value in new FormData object ? is there any way

Comment: using loop in php file? My controller file

Comment: not work's i have to send all the data through ajax in my controller but in my ajax i am getting only 1 image value,

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` use this in controller and share the result in your question

Comment: https://prnt.sc/mqbrwv here's the screenshot

Comment: u r only getting 1 file f

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633610/multiple-file-upload-in-each-inputs-using-codeigniter-and-ajax

Comment: yeah bro i am getting only one file

Comment: check duplicate or given below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can loop through file and send it to server.**

```js
let files = [];
let inputFile = $('#file');
 inputFile.change(function() {
    let newFiles = []; 
    for(let index = 0; index < inputFile[0].files.length; index++) {
      let file = inputFile[0].files[index];
      newFiles.push(file);
      files.push(file);
    }



  console.log('files all files', files);


  var formData = new FormData();
                files.forEach(file => {
                  formData.append('attachment[]', file);
                });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple />
```